# Prove an infinite series hypothesis

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

If I have a hypothesis that this function will work for any given a or b value (greater than zero and one respectively), how would I go about "proving" that... What exactly is considered a "proof" in mathematics?

also, does this function have a name?

$$\sum_{c=1}^\infty \frac a {b^c} = \frac a {b-1}$$

Answer (score 2):

Your hypothesis is incorrect. Consider what happens if $|b|\le 1$.

This type of series does have a name: it is a [geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series).

Comment: Okay, so lets say a>0 and b>1... then how do I prove it?

Comment: Edited this into the original question for better clarification.

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite correct in its present form; for example, consider a = 1 and b = 1/2; in this case, the sum would become

$$\sum\limits_{c = 1}^{\infty} 2^c $$

which is clearly divergent.

But what you are considering is called a [geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series), and has a finite limit for all |b| > 1; this limit agrees with the formula you've given. The linked article gives a [sketch of a proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula) using a closed formula for finite partial sums and evaluating a limit.